# Error: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'

Tags: python

My code is in file Test.py

```
name = input("enter your name :")
id = int(input("enter your id :")
score = [int]*3
MyLib.calculate(score)
MyLib.result(name, id, score)
```

And this the code in MyLib.py

```
def calculate (x) :
    n = 0
    for n in x :
        nilai = int(input("Input Your Score : "))
def result (a,b,c) :
    n = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in c :
        if n >= 80 and n <= 100 :
            i = 4
            x = "A" 
        elif n < 80 and n >= 70 :
            i = 3
            x = "B"
        elif n < 70 and n >= 60 :
            i = 2
            x = "C"
        elif n < 60 and n >= 50 :
            i = 1
            x = "D"
        elif n < 50 and n >= 0 :
            i = 0
            x = "E"
        sum += i
    print("Your Name :",a)
    print("Your ID :", b)
    print("Your score number is ",n," and your score alphabet is ",x)
    print("Your avg score is", sum)
```

But after i input the score (ex. 80, 70, 60) the result is TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. I assume you're looking for debugging help, so you need to provide a [mre]. This code is incomplete, but I can safely assume that you `import MyLib`. With just that, it shouldn't raise an error, but it doesn't really do anything, since `result()` is never called. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: `MyLib.calculate(score)` doesn't return anything, and you don't capture its result. What were you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it's not like you want.  The relevant question is if it sufficiently answers your question or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
score = [int]*3
```

produces the list

```
[int, int, int]
```

When you pass `score` to `MyLib.calculate`, you iterate over each element (i.e., each `int`) and create the local variable `nilai` which holds the value entered by the user.

However, `nilai` is reassigned to each new input meaning that you lose the previous value.  Furthermore, you never return any of these values which mean that they are lost forever.

`score` then gets passed to `result`.  It is then iterated over.  In each iteration, `n` is equal to `int` since that's the only element in the list.

You compare `int` to 80 in the line

```
if n >= 80 and n <= 100:
```

`int` is an object of type `type`.  It makes no sense to compare a `type` object to 80 which is an integer.

Try replacing `MyLib.calculate` with the following.

```
def calculate(length):
    scores = []
    for _ in range(length):
        nilai = int(input("Input Your Score : "))
        scores.append(nilai)
    return scores
```

You can then call

```
scores = MyLib.calculate(3)
```